# Spool in Shell script not working for me

Tags: oracle, linux, sqlplus

```
#!/bin/sh

echo "Started at" `date +%Y/%m/%d" "%H:%M:%S`

sqlplus -s ${ORA_LOGIN_SYSADM} <<EOF 2>&1 > /dev/null
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
SET FEED OFF
spool ech.txt create
BEGIN
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('xyz');
END;
/
spool off
EOF


if [ $? -ne 0 ]
then
   echo " ech.sh sql   Error"
   exit 1
else
   echo " ech.sh  Successful"
fi
```

I am getting an SQL error message. Any ideas?

Comment: Are you doing this from a client? As far as I know, DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE sends output to a file on the server, not on the client.

Comment: Is this the exact text of your script?  As posted, it will not run.  For example, `!/bin/sh` should be `#!/bin/sh`.  There are other syntax errors as well.  Can you post the full script that runs and gives you the error message?

Comment: Remove the `/dev/null` redirect so you can see exactly what's going on, then edit the question with the information

Comment: Edit made by @Mat to fix the script works for me.

Comment: (I didn't fix anything in the script, @ansible. It's just markdown that likes to eat stuff that could potentially look like html outside of code blocks. Adding whitespace was enough.)

Comment: Maybe ... you should tell us WHAT SQL error you get ? What I don't like is that the variable ORA_LOGIN_SYSADM is unchecked by the script. I suspect the error may be related to that. But as long as you suppress output, debugging is harder.

Comment: Mat - thanks for clarifying.  I believe @tvCa is correct about the variable being at least part of the problem; the script as written only worked when I supplied credentials in place of the variable.

Answer (score 2):

I took some code snippets from a backup script that I use. 
You can redirect all output with the exec command, then 
redirect it back. You can also surround everything with 
braces and redirect that to a log file.

Personally I think bash is a better shell to program in, 
if you don't have bash ksh works too.

```
#!/bin/bash

export MY_LOG_FILE=my_log_file.log

exec >${MY_LOG_FILE}
exec 2>&1

export ORACLE_BASE=/home/oracle/admin
export ORACLE_HOME=/software/oracle/product/11.2.0
export TNS_ADMIN=${ORACLE_HOME}/network/admin
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=${ORACLE_HOME}/lib:${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}
export ORACLE_SID=mysid


echo "Started at" `date +%Y/%m/%d" "%H:%M:%S`

sqlplus -s ${ORA_LOGIN_SYSADM} <<EOF
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
SET FEED OFF
BEGIN
   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('xyz');
END;
/
EOF

exec 1>&-
exec 2>&-
exec >/dev/tty
exec 2>&1

if [ `egrep -n "ORA-|RMAN-" ${MY_LOG_FILE}` -ne 0 ]
then
   echo " ech.sh sql   Error"
   egrep -n "ORA-|RMAN-" ${MY_LOG_FILE}
   exit 1
else
   echo " ech.sh  Successful"
fi
```